# how long it will take: change ios app from paid to free

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an iOS app in appstore, before yesterday I was using Tier2 $1.99. Yesterday I changed it to Tier0 Free.

Almost 24 hours passed, I still see it shows $1.99 in appstore.

Anyone knows how long it will take? Or everytime if I change the price, I should resubmit the app again to make it available?

Thanks a lot.
[image: Screenshot of "Pricing and Availability"]

Comment: Normally this only takes minutes, sometimes an hour. Have you tried to reload the App Store?

Comment: @dasdom Sure. I tried it on my ipad, restart App Store app, search my app again, it still shows 1.99.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't do anything but just wait. Now It finally becomes free, for my situation, I think it is less than 36 hours.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the "button" (i.e. the price that gets shown on the App Store) takes way longer to update than what you app actually costs (i.e. if someone would buy/download your app).

Lot's of information is also stored in the locale catch. Did you just visit the page on your iPad? Restarting the App Store app does not help in all situations. If you can provide us with a link, more people from different regions/locales etc. can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think it is already updated to free. Some people say it will less than 24 hours, not knowing why my take such long time.